# MomentJS: Why do format() and toISOString() yield different results?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

According to the documentation, the `moment` methods `toISOString()` and `format()` both yield strings formatted according to ISO 8601. However, the strings produced by either method differ from the other. For example:

`moment("2015-12-31T10:28:41+01:00").toISOString()`

yields

`"2015-12-31T09:28:41.000Z"`

whereas

`moment("2015-12-31T10:28:41+01:00").format()`

yields

`"2015-12-31T10:28:41+01:00"`

Why is this, and are these strings fully equivalent in all computational circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `toISOString` function mimics the `Date` object's `toISOString` function, in that it converts all values to UTC before formatting, then uses the `Z` character to indicate UTC.

The `format` function doesn't do any conversions itself.  It relies on whatever state the `moment` object is in to determine which time zone offset to use.

The `format` function also accepts parameters to control the string representation.  When no parameter is passed, the default is the ISO8601 extended format *with offset*.

From a practical perspective, note that `format` will use `+00:00` when called on a moment in UTC mode, instead of `Z` that is used by `toISOString`.  Either are allowed by ISO8601, but `Z` specifically indicates UTC while `+00:00` could also be from a time zone that just happens to be aligned to GMT at that moment.  For example, the UK uses `+00:00` in the winter and `+01:00` in the summer.

Also recognize the ISO8601 covers many different formats, including:

- Standard timestamp format `YYYYMMDDTHHMMSSZ`
- Extended timestamp format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`
- Explicit offset versions of the standard and extended formats
- Timezoneless versions of the standard and extended formats
- Date-only and time-only versions of the standard and extended formats
- Week-number based formats
- Duration / Period formats

It's also worth noting that [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) limits this to the extended timestamp format, disallowing the timezoneless form, and allowing a few subtle deviations from ISO8601.

Both `.format()` and `.toISOString()` are RFC3339 compliant.

Oh, and your example is slightly off.  `moment("2015-12-31T10:28:41+01:00").format()` will only yield `"2015-12-31T10:28:41+01:00"` if the local time zone happens to match.  Otherwise, the value is converted to the local time zone, showing the relevant offset for that zone.  If you want to keep the input offset regardless of local time zone, use:

```
moment.parseZone("2015-12-31T10:28:41+01:00").format()
```